# Stored procedure to return rows with unique columns

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a SQL Server 2008 table with the following columns:

```
ID = uniqueidentifier
EntryID = uniqueidentifier
EntryType = nvarchar(128)
```

In this table some of the rows may have the same `EntryType` value. What I want to do is run a query that will return me the rows where the `EntryType` field is unique. The only way I thought of doing this is to group by this field then check for groups with just a single entry. Here is some example data:

```
11C5AEEB-6435-489D-B353-6E8D63FCD1AD, 46F95579-0AB6-4EAC-927C-7259C2F1E046, Ford
01DBC8EE-78E4-4544-A816-87086BD45DDE, EBB689E3-1379-4E22-98B2-C6BD8EBB0F9D, VW
E948C6D2-0E6E-4AC7-9799-83C5EB180219, 46F95579-0AB6-4EAC-927C-7259C2F1E046, Ford
E70806DC-9D43-4341-AEF8-4252612AF00B, 3A3D2602-DB92-412B-AA4E-8FA70438A00A, Ford
D4460A15-2C4B-475E-B5D9-82C625C10DF7, 3EA31E10-4941-46D3-B241-B091259A2AF4, Lexus
```

I want to run a stored procedure that when applied to the above data will just return the `VW` entry as the `EntryType` column is unique.

Comment: Why isn't the Lexus row also unique?

Comment: Aaron - You are quite right, Lexus is also unique. I wrote this in a rush as I was just leaving work. Well spotted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
;WITH x AS 
(
  -- first, identify rows where only one EntryType exists:
  SELECT EntryType FROM dbo.table_name
  GROUP BY EntryType HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
)
-- now join to that from the main table:
SELECT t.ID, t.EntryID, t.EntryType
  FROM dbo.table_name AS t
  INNER JOIN x 
  ON x.EntryType = t.EntryType;
```

Comment: @Mike the difference in method is irrelevant. I down-voted your post not because you used a subquery but because your queries don't solve the problem (and I wasn't the only one if you look closely - one blind up-vote and TWO down-votes). Please consider correcting your logic (or proving that it is correct) instead of seeking vengeance.

Answer (score 1):

In SQL Server 2008 you can use [count()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175997%28v=sql.100%29.aspx) with [over()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461%28v=sql.100%29.aspx).

```
select T.ID, T.EntryID, T.EntryType
from
  (
  select ID, EntryID, EntryType,
         count(*) over(partition by EntryType) as C
  from YourTable
  ) as T
where T.C = 1
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f20df/3/0)

The derived table will give you

```
ID          EntryID     EntryType  C
--------    --------    ---------  --
11C5AEEB..  46F95579..  Ford       3
E948C6D2..  46F95579..  Ford       3
E70806DC..  3A3D2602..  Ford       3
D4460A15..  3EA31E10..  Lexus      1
01DBC8EE..  EBB689E3..  VW         1
```

And the main query picks the rows where the count `C` is 1.